# Can't access remote SQL Server instance even if its firewall its disabled

Tags: sql-server, remote-access

I'm trying to remotely access to an old SQL Server 2005 instance in order to port some data over to another server, however I am unable to access to the database while using my database administrator tool (DBeaver).

Via Remote Desktop I can access the server and make changes, and I verified the Windows Firewall was indeed disabled, even so I can't seem to connect to the database since the connection times out. It's not a problem in my end since I can access other database servers (both MSSQL and MySQL/MariaDB) without problems.

Trying to access the Windows Firewall option from the control panel throws a message box that says `Windows Firewall cannot run because another program or service is running that might use the network address translation component (Ipnat.sys)`. A quick google revealed that this might be a problem with RRAS, but even after disabling that service the firewall service couldn't start to be accessed.

Note that I can't use Microsoft's SSMS since my workspace uses a Linux OS.

The remote system uses Windows Server 2003.

I appreciate any help with this issue.

Tools used: DBeaver 5.1.1, Remmina Remote Desktop Client

Comment: If you can RDP to the server then surely you can run SSMS locally on the server. Have you tried that?

Comment: @joeqwerty I have no problem running SSMS locally in the server, but I need to do a lot of queries and then export the data results to CSV files and I can't seem to transfer heavy files remotely.

Comment: Why not take a copy or backup of the database to your local machine and work on it there?

Comment: @joeqwerty I can't transfer the backup files, since the only browser available (iexplore) can't access websites. I tried to connect to a site like wetransfer with no avail.

Comment: In SQL Server Configuration Manager, which communication methods are open?  Have you verified the TCP/IP port is the same as you are trying to connect with?

Answer (score 0):

RDP to the server and open SQL Server Configuration Manager, then navigate to SQL Server Network Configuration, then select the protocol for the installed instance.  Check TCP/IP in the right window and make sure it is enabled.  If not, enable it and restart the SQL Server service.

Comment: TCP/IP is enabled.

Comment: Can you telnet to port 1433 (default SQL port unless it's a named instance or custom install) from a remote host?  If not then there is a firewall or the instance is running on a different port.  Double click TCP/IP and find the port for the AllIP.

Answer (score 0):

If Windows Firewall is disabled you can try these steps:

- Make RDP connection to server
- Stop SQL Browser service
- Change the SQL Server port number.

Information about port number can be found in "SQL Server Configuration Manager".

Path is "SQL Server Network Configuration\Protocols for [instance name]", "TCP/IP", "TCP/IP Properties" dialog box, "IP Addresses" tab, section "IPAll". 
To change the port number just leave "TCP Dynamci port" empty. Set "TCP Port" to desired port number (could be default 1433). Stop "SQLBrowser" service and restart SQL Server service.

After these steps you can try to connect to SQL server with "server\instance,port" syntax.